# The degree of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},w): \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Compute the degree of the field extension $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},w): \mathbb{Q} ,$$ where $ w = e^{2\pi i / 3}$.

I consider the tower of fields $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})(w)$ now, $\mathbb{Q}: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ has degree $2$, so I am trying to find the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})(w)$ it is $\leq 2$ since $w $ satisfies $w^2+w+1 = 0$. I am trying to show that it is exactly $2$ - I know that $ w \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ but I don't see how I can justify it is exactly $2$ from here.

Comment: The degree of $w$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ can be either $1$ or $2$.  It can't be $1$ because if it were, $w$ would belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, which is not the case. So it must be $2$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen could you explain why if the degree is 1 it implies $w \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: If $K\subseteq L$ is a field extension and $x\in L$ is of degree $1$ over $K$ then $[K(x):K]=1$ so $K(x)=K$ so $x\in K$; or, if you prefer, $x$ is the root of a degree $1$ polynomial over $K$, so it is in $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)(w) : \Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)]$ is $\leq 2$ (as $w^2 + w + 1 = 0$), it is either $1$ or $2$, and it is $1$ iff $w \in \sqrt{5}$. Since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5) \leq \Bbb R$ but $w \not \in \Bbb R$, we must have $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)(w) : \Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)] = 2$.

Comment: could you explain why if the degree is 1 it implies $w \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: This says that as a vector space over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})(w)$ is $1$-dimensional, that is, that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})(w) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$.